# Homomorphism Exist? Groups

Tags: group-theory

[image]

**Attempt:** I was hoping if someone could help me on figuring out if an homomorphism exists for the 4 cases below. I managed to figure out the ones before, but these ones are proving to be rather tricky, thanks.

Comment: Hint: For the first two, consider the determinant and the sign of a permutation, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, the determinant is the necessary homomorphism. The second sends a cycle to its signum. The third is the quotient map from $O(3)$ to the quotient of $O(3)$ by its center $\{\pm I\}$. For the fourth, there is none, because the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup of the domain, but $S_3$ has no subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: For fourth no homomorphism is possible because no subgroup of order $2$ is normal in $S_3$.

Comment: Yes! Good call, good call.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The kernels are normal subgroups.

For $O(3)$ determinants are a natural way to think.

In $S_3$ the only normal subgroups are $\{e\}, S_3, \{(1\, 2 \, 3)\}$. Therefore the kernels can only be among these. As you can see there are no normal subgroups of order $2$, hence you cannot have a homomorphism from $S_3$ with kernel of order $2$.

Use this line of thinking for other parts and hopefully you will be able to do it yourself.